# Assigning multiple properties from delimited csv columns in neo4j Cypher

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

Reading from csv, I am creating a simple graph DB with "scotch" and "region" nodes.

I wish to assign properties to the scotch node for pipe delimited fields. The catch is, each field instance does not necessarily contain the same number of delimited values.

For a single field, here 'NOSE' (which can contain e.g. 'FRESH' or 'FRESH|SEA' or 'FRESH|SEA|FRUIT'), I successfully run the following query:

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///scotch_narrow.csv' AS line

 WITH line, SPLIT(line.NOSE, '|') AS v1

 CREATE (scotch:Scotch {name: line.SCOTCH, nose: v1})

 MERGE (region:REGION {name: line.REGION, district: line.DISTRICT})

 CREATE (scotch)-[:MADE_IN]->(region)
```

I then try to assign multiple properties at once using the same paradigm as below:

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
 'file:///scotch_narrow.csv' AS line

 WITH line, SPLIT(line.NOSE, '|') AS v1
 WITH line, SPLIT(line.BODY, '|') AS v2
 WITH line, SPLIT(line.FINISH, '|') AS v3
 WITH line, SPLIT(line.PALETTE, '|') AS v4

 CREATE (scotch:Scotch {name: line.SCOTCH, nose: v1, body: v2, finish: v3, palette: v4})

 MERGE (region:REGION {name: line.REGION, district: line.DISTRICT})

 CREATE (scotch)-[:MADE_IN]->(region)
```

I then get an error; variable 'v2' is not being defined:

```
 Variable `v2` not defined (line 4, column 115 (offset: 178))
 "WITH line, SPLIT(line.NOSE, '|'), SPLIT(line.BODY, '|'),
 SPLIT(line.FINISH, '|'), SPLIT(line.PALETTE, '|') AS v1, v2, v3, v4"
```

Where has my syntax gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WITH changes what variables are in scope, and if a variable that was defined before is not included in the WITH clause, it is no longer in scope.

Your series of WITHs introduces new variables (your "v" variables), but you leave them out of the next WITH, so they immediately go out of scope. You want to include them with each new WITH, so v1 should be included in the second WITH, and both v1 and v2 should be in your third WITH, etc.

That should solve your syntax issue.

You might also want to consider modeling these values as nodes of the given labels (e.g. nodes of a :Nose label that have values for fresh, sea, and fruit) and creating relationships to each of your :Scotches, at least if you plan on creating queries that find :Scotches based upon some set of characteristics. If not, then what you're doing now should be just fine.

Comment: Excellent, thank you @InverseFalcon - modifying the "WITH" part of my query solved my syntax issue.

Thank you for your recommendation to model the properties as nodes, this exercise will be helpful in ramping up my understanding of graph DB capabilities.